# Django Model Objects cannot seen in Django Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

Rendered django model object cannot give any output in template. My Code is:

model.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    address = models.GenericIPAddressField(
        max_length=15,
        verbose_name=_('address')
    )
    Path = models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
        verbose_name='path',
    )
    activate = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='off', )
```

views.py:

```
class MyView(ListView):
    model = models.MyModel.objects.all()[0]
    template_name = '../on_off.html'
    context_object_name = 'obj_list'
```

admin.py:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('address', 'Path', )
    exclude = ('activate', )
    change_list_template = '../on_off.html'
```

on_off.html:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% block object-tools %}
 {% if obj_list %}
     <form id="on_off_status" method="POST">
         <label id="onoff" class="switch">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" value=" {{ obj_list.activate }} ">
             <div class="slider round"></div>
         </label>
     </form>
 {% endif %}
...
```

In Django model, the system accepts only one object and I want to give to toggle switch button value in template using activate field in MyModel model. But it is not rendered in template, I couldn't get any object data even if I try `<h1> {{ obj_list }} </h1>`, it turns `<h1> </h1>` . Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the views.py, django-admin provide a function named `changelist_view()`. Now it is working, I deleted the funtion in views.py and I added `changelist_view()` function to my admin.py looks like:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('address', 'Path',)
exclude = ('activate',)
change_list_template = '../nfs_on_off.html'

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    object = self.model.objects.all()
    context={
        'obj_list': object,
    }
    return super(MyAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the field manually

```
<label id="onoff" class="switch">
{% csrf_token %}
      {{ obj_list.activate }}
   <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```